# Pyqt5 FileSystem

Tags: python, pyqt5

Good afternoon!
I have my own text editor in PyQt5, and the problem is that after compiling it to .exe. Try.open the txt file with my editor from the desktop, but I get nothing. I use the Qplaintextedit widget.
I suspect that there is not enough at the start of the file check. Please tell me what methods there are or examples. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! It's not really clear from your question what exactly you are trying to do. Since you didn't add code, we also can't really help you debugging what might be the problem. It would help if you updated your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your import code so we can take a better look.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.